# Ionic cordova, android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity>

Tags: xml, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am updating my android-targetSdkVersion to 32. I have done a few changes on my project for this update, but there is an error for which I can't find any solution.

When I try to build my project by:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

My project responds:

> FCMPlugin: Support for Gradle v4 or lower is deprecated. Please
> upgrade to a newer version.
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED {project}/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:64:9-69:20
> Error:
> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <activity#com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.FCMPluginActivity>. Apps targeting
> Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for
> `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent
> filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details.
> {project}/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:40:9-44:19
> Error:
> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#com.gae.scaffolder.plugin.MyFirebaseMessagingService>. Apps
> targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit
> value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an
> intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details.
> {project}/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:52:9-56:20
> Error:
> android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#nl.xservices.plugins.ShareChooserPendingIntent>. Apps
> targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit
> value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an
> intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details.
>
> See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information
> about the manifest merger.
>
> FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
>
> ### 1: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
>   Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile resource file: {project}/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml:
>   . Cause: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace
>   prefix "android" (for attribute "exported")
>   at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [99,44]). Check logs for more details.
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   ==============================================================================
>
> ### 2: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
>   Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   ==============================================================================
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
>
> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation
> warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
>
> See
> https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 34s 16 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 14 up-to-date
> Command failed with exit code 1:
> {project}/platforms/android/gradlew
> cdvBuildDebug -b
> {project}/platforms/android/build.gradle
> Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...

If have tried going to my /plugins folder, search the plugin and add it into it's plugin.xml

```
android:exported="true"
```

But still, it's not generating the 'android:exported="true"' into my AndroidManifest.xml...

Has anybody had this problem before? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you add 'android:exported="true"' to the activity and service tags in plugin.xml?
If you have already added this in both tags then try to remove and add the android platform.

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same issue and fix with two ways

**First method:**

navigate to plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/plugin.xml and then add **android:exported="true"** like below..

```
<activity android:exported="true" ... </activity>
.
.
.
 <service android:exported="true" ... </service>
```

**Second Method:**

I forked this plugin and fix issue so you can try to install forked github plugin From [This link](https://github.com/alitalaee/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated-12)

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated-12
```

Hope it will Help :)